# SQL Server 2000 on Win7 64bit

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have tried to install SQL Server 2000 on Win7 OS. It is able to install but the SQL Server service manager doesn't have any instances to start the service.

Has anyone ever resolved this thing before?

Need help on this

Comment: [See this support policy post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028963) - SQL Server 2000 is officially **NOT SUPPORTED** on Windows 7. Time to upgrade!

Comment: I knew marc.  But the old server files I have doesnt work on 2008 servers.  :( are there ways to overcome this?

Comment: You should be easily able to backup on SQL Server 2000, and restore these backups on anything up to SQL Server **2008 R2** (2012 and 2014 do not support restoring backups from 2000 anymore)

Comment: Actually that is another way to solve my problem. A work around. The actual problem I have is I have an old exe file which can query,execute from the sql 2000 db.  I cant seem to use this to work on sql 2008 so I have to work back on sql 2000 on win7.

Comment: The exe was created 10 years ago by some  game developer. This exe can actually help us in managing the db very well and fast.  So I kinda dont want to waste this file